# Github.com Wiki Automated Sidebar Links not working

Tags: github, navigation, sidebar, wiki

Hi I am currently updating the companies wiki pages and we use the side bar of the github wiki to navigate through them.  I have noticed that the header links listed on the github sidebar no longer takes me to that section of the page.  You can see from the image the link at the bottom does not include the section in the url like it used to.  Is this a me thing or a github thing?

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing this too suddenly. It was working as of a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the github team and they are aware
[image]